# ipad resizing images > 2048 px wide

Tags: css, ipad

I'm more annoyed right now than I have been in years over web dev...

My iPad2 is scaling any image over 2048px wide to 50% of its original size.  Wondering if anyone has a solutions to this.

Demo:

http://misc.clientsite.me/img-size/2048.jpg

http://misc.clientsite.me/img-size/2049.jpg

the ipad says the 2nd one is 1025x512 even though it's really 2049x1024.  The problem is that it believes this, no matter what.... WTF?!?!?!?!?!?!

Comment: I found this, might help: http://www.defusion.org.uk/archives/2010/02/19/shrinking-large-background-image-bug-in-iphone-safari/
See "Know iOS Resource Limits" at http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution: progressive jpgs